# how to print dynamic variable value in php

Tags: php

how to get value or same name variable but end with different index

```
 $item1='100';
 $item2='200';
 $item3='300';
 $item4='400';
 $item5='500';

 for ($i=1;$i<4;$i++){
    echo '--'.$($item.$i); // or echo '--'.$.'item'.$i);
 }
```

i have variable $item1,2,3,.... i don't know how many item variable i got . i got total no of item variable so i want to go with loop and print all item variable value . i write above code but error occur . any one know how to get each item value ????

Comment: Why not using [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: in my case array not possible . other wise with array all is very simple

Comment: @Affan explain why you can't save values to array indexes, but can save them to random named variables...

Comment: i don't know why people give negative marking without give any solution . solution is there . i place $($itme) instead of {} .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like

```
echo '--'.${"item" . $i};
```

Refer [**this**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).And better you use an array like

```
$item[1]='100';
$item[2]='200';
$item[3]='300';
$item[4]='400';
$item[5]='500';
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use an array. But if you need to use dynamic variables, the syntax is:

```
echo '--'.${$item.$i};
```

See [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: yes i understand but i work with payment method and it provide me only variable and each time different no of variable so i need this . after get this i will create array from this and do my further process . thanks for help @Barmar